# Как открыть приложение на Android через сайт?

Tags: javascript, html, android, jquery

Есть сайт. На сайте есть кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку хочу, чтобы открывалось определенное приложение (в данной ситуации - **Microsoft Teams**). Как такое реализовать? Устройство **Android**, но, для общего развития, хотелось бы узнать, как открыть и на **IOS** :)

Comment: [Унифицированный Указатель Ресурса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

Comment: Здесь посмотрите https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ссылку вида `<a href='callto:teams_email'>я в тимс</a>` и стилизуйте её как кнопку.

Аналогично работают префиксы `sip:` и `tel:`

Comment: а как мне получить путь и название приложения? Просто в проводник зайти? Примерно, как он должен выглядеть (путь)?

Comment: @ВладимирПечерский это не так работает. Система видит указание протокола при переходе по ссылке и дает список вариантов приложений (при их наличии) которые поддерживают данный протокол. Со стороны сайта на это повлиять никак нельзя. А вот в установленном у вас microsoft teams уже прописано, что он может как-то обрабатывать такие ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, в моем случае мне понадобилось лишь загуглить: "URL Microsoft Teams", там все расписано. Просто просто в `<a href="ссылка">я в тимс</a>`